# With bibliography style "achemso" publishing years of books aren't bold

Tags: bibliographies, bold, books, achemso

I'm currently using achemso as my bibliography style. And i have to cite some books, but unlike for papers the publishing year for the books does not appear in bold numbers. Does anybody have an idea how to change that? 
I have only tried putting \textbf{} in the .bib file but that produces an error (improper alphabetic constant) and i read that there are only numbers allowed in the "years bracket".

Well here is my example:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[super,square,sort&compress,comma]{natbib}

\begin{document}

See XYZ\cite{Reichardt2004,Clark2006}

\bibliographystyle{achemso}
\bibliography{Bibliography}
\end{document
```

and these are the .bib entries:

```
@Article{Clark2006,
  Title                    = {Green chemistry: today (and tomorrow)},
  Author                   = {Clark, James H.},
  Journal                  = {Green Chem.},
  Year                     = {2006},
  Pages                    = {17-21},
  Volume                   = {8},

  Issue                    = {1},
  Publisher                = {The Royal Society of Chemistry}
}

@InBook{Reichardt2004,
  Title                    = {Front Matter},
  Author                   = {Reichardt, Christian},
  Pages                    = {i--xxvi},
  Publisher                = {Wiley-VCH Verlag GmbH \& Co. KGaA},
  Year                     = {2004},

  Booktitle                = {Solvents and Solvent Effects in Organic Chemistry}
}
```

And here is how it looks for me:

[image]

I use TeXnicCenter 2.02 and Miktex 2.9. Compiling: LaTex -> PS -> PDF

Thank you very much for your help!

Mido

Comment: This is 'by design': the ACS only use bold for the year for journal articles.

Answer (score 2):

THE ACS only use bold for years when the entry is a journal: other types of reference do not have this formatting. As such, the `achemso` style simply does what is 'required'.